# Why can't a Variant contain a TDateTime before 100 CE?

Tags: delphi

Consider the following code:

```
procedure Test;
  function d1: Variant;
  var
    DDt: TDateTime;
  begin
    DDt := EncodeDate(100,1,1);
    Result := DDt;
  end;
  function d2: Variant;
  var
    DDt: TDateTime;
  begin
    DDt := EncodeDate(99,12,31);
    Result := DDt;
  end;
  procedure Writedate(V: Variant);
  begin
    Writeln(string(V));
  end;
var
  V: Variant;
begin
  V := d1;
  Writedate(V);
  V := d2;
  Writedate(V);
end;
```

The first call to `Writedate` will succeed, and the output will be '01-01-0100'.  The second call, however, will fail with an 'invalid argument' failure.  Inspecting the code, you can see the `Variant` of the 99-12-31 date has a `EVariantInvalidArgError` error.

However, if I call `FormatDateTime('c', TDateTime(V))` on either `TDateTime`, they will both succeed.  In fact, at any point when the `Variant` contains a `TDateTime`, whose date is before 100 CE, the IDE will display a `EVariantInvalidArgError` when inspecting its value.

It seems odd that the `Variant` cannot handle the pre-100 CE date, when `TDateTime` can.  Is this a bug in Delphi?  I find it being *right* between 99 and 100 CE to be a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Variant` can contain any date value, as your code demonstrates (assignment `V := d2;` produces no error).

The error is raised during the conversion to string which the compiler delegates to the OS on Windows platforms. This fails because [OLE Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx) specifies midnight, 1 January 0100 as the minimum valid OLE Automation date value.

Comment: I thought Delphi stopped using Windows Variants many versions ago.  But Variants still rely on OLE Automation?

Comment: The whole point of the Variant type is that it is an interop type

Comment: There are several variant conversions which are delegated to OLE Automation. You are casting a `VT_DATE` variant to a string. This is done by calling the API `VarBstrFromDate` in `oleaut32.dll` (see `System.Variants` and `System.VarUtils`). You can step through the code (compiled with debug dcus) and see for yourself.